# how to programmatically handle null output within a bash function with some custom formatting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, string-formatting

I have a bash function that uses a list of IPs in `result` and for each IP, its used as part of a database query to return a string.  What I need help with now is how to handle the output, **if the IP does NOT return data** (see the testoutput)

The code:

```
set -x
demo() {
        local result='10.8.3.34
        10.8.2.191
        10.8.3.54
        10.8.4.150
        10.8.3.249
        10.8.2.197'
        read -d '' -a servers <<< $result
        echo "Checking ${#servers[@]} servers";
        for i in ${servers[@]};
        do
          local host='10.1.2.130'
          local db='myapplication_cluster_state'
          _mongo=$(which mongo);
          echo -n "$i:";
          local exp="db.myapplicationcluster_servers.find(
          {\"node_host\":\"${i}\",\"node_type\":\"APP_PROCESS\",\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"status\":\"ACTIVE\"},{\"partition_range_start\":1,\"partition_range_end\":1, _id:0}).pretty();";
          ${_mongo} ${host}/${db} --eval "$exp" | grep -o -e "{[^}]*}";
        done
}
set +x
demo
```

My **testoutput**:

```
+ set +x
Checking 6 servers
10.8.3.34:{ "partition_range_start" : 31, "partition_range_end" : 31 }
10.8.2.191:{ "partition_range_start" : 79, "partition_range_end" : 79 }
10.8.3.54:{ "partition_range_start" : 62, "partition_range_end" : 62 }
10.8.4.150:{ "partition_range_start" : 22, "partition_range_end" : 22 }
10.8.3.249:10.8.2.197:{ "partition_range_start" : 16, "partition_range_end" : 16 }
```

Note: `10.8.3.249` has NO data, so the next string is appended as `10.8.3.249:10.8.2.197:{ "partition_range_start"`

I would like the output **format** to be this:

```
+ set +x
Checking 6 servers
10.8.3.34:{ "partition_range_start" : 31, "partition_range_end" : 31 }
10.8.2.191:{ "partition_range_start" : 79, "partition_range_end" : 79 }
10.8.3.54:{ "partition_range_start" : 62, "partition_range_end" : 62 }
10.8.4.150:{ "partition_range_start" : 22, "partition_range_end" : 22 }
10.8.3.249:
10.8.2.197:{ "partition_range_start" : 16, "partition_range_end" : 16 }
```

**OR**  *If no data for the IP that is read, put some value, i.e. EMPTY*

```
10.8.3.34:{ "partition_range_start" : 31, "partition_range_end" : 31 }
10.8.2.191:{ "partition_range_start" : 79, "partition_range_end" : 79 }
10.8.3.54:{ "partition_range_start" : 62, "partition_range_end" : 62 }
10.8.4.150:{ "partition_range_start" : 22, "partition_range_end" : 22 }
10.8.3.249: EMPTY
10.8.2.197:{ "partition_range_start" : 16, "partition_range_end" : 16 }
```

How can I achieve this output? Thanks.

Comment: No need to include semi-colons

Comment: catch output of last command and test for emptiness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `for` loop to…

```
for i in ${servers[@]}
do
  local host='10.1.2.130'
  local db='myapplication_cluster_state'
  _mongo=$(which mongo)
  local exp="db.myapplicationcluster_servers.find({\"node_host\":\"${i}\",\"node_type\":\"APP_PROCESS\",\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"status\":\"ACTIVE\"},{\"partition_range_start\":1,\"partition_range_end\":1, _id:0}).pretty();"

  # Store output of mongo command in variable
  output=$(${_mongo} ${host}/${db} --eval "$exp" | grep -o -e "{[^}]*}")

  # Print {} if output variable is empty
  echo "${i}:${output:-{}}"
done
```

To switch `{}` with nothing, use `echo "${i}:${output:-}"`

To switch `{}` with `EMPTY`, use `echo "${i}:${output:- EMPTY}"`

## Sorting

To sort on the value of `partition_range_start`, pipe the output of the `demo` function to the `sort` command…

```
demo | sort -n -k4
```

This says "sort the output of `demo` numerically (`-n`) on field 4 (`-k4`)". Fields are, by default, characters separated by whitespace.

This is what `sort` sees for the line `10.8.3.34:{ "partition_range_start" : 31, "partition_range_end" : 31 }`...

- field 1 `10.8.3.34:{`
- field 2 `"partition_range_start"`
- field 3 `:`
- field 4 `31,`
- field 5 `"partition_range_end"`
- field 6 `:`
- field 7 `31`
- field 8 `}`

Comment: Would you also know how to sort the output? For example: `10.8.2.197:{ "partition_range_start" : 16, "partition_range_end" : 16 }` would be listed first. So the sort would be on `partition_range_start` with lowest to highest?

Comment: Thanks again! Nice breakdown on the use of sort.